# fields nested in table are decorated twice after page switch

Tags: jquery-mobile

I get a table to be filled in data by JavaScript, there is a table with single template row with few columns, and are hidden by css, when server returns data, program clone the template row to multiple rows and fill in data to columns of them.

Now, there is a strange thing, if the table is in same page, all things work fine, but if I try to add a new page (i.e. ) and fill in data and then go to new page (i.e. jQuery.mobile.changePage("#newPage")), after new page shown, all cloned rows are processed twice (i.e. I guess that the 'create' event is fired twice), the decoration get duplicate, there are 2 div tag for single input field,

i.e. a input tag is decorated to following:

```
    <td style="min-width: 70px;">
    <b class="ui-table-cell-label">Price</b>
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled ui-shadow-inset">
    <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-state-disabled ui-shadow-inset">
    <input data-meta-column="TxnGridTxnPrc" disabled="disabled">
    </div></div>
    </td>
```

, but original template row looks correct, just cloned rows get duplicates, I also debugged my JavaScript function, after cloned and filled in data and before I go to new page, all things OK (checked DOM tree by Developer Tools of Chrome browser); my program do not fire selectmenu("refresh") or similar calling, the new page is created and loaded by JavaScript, my understanding is, if 'create' event is already fired before I fill data, then cloned rows also get decorations and no need to be decorated again.

, how to avoid it?

There is a screen dump for demo:
[image: Screen dump]

Comment: The problem is that your template row is being 'enhanced' by jQM and you are cloning the already enhanced objects.  If you want to load rows on another page, you could put your template in script, or if you leave it in the markup, put it in an invisible DOM element outside of any data-role="page" divs.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I will move it outside of page element, it seems that jQM cannot know if or not my UI component is enhanced before it show new page and cloning template row cannot clone 'invisible underlying' attributes (template row and cloned rows are shown in same page, but they looks different).